# Custom Events from User Control to Parent Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple TabControl inside my UserControl which is embedded in the parent control like this:

```
 <StackPanel>       
        <myviews:myusercontrol></myviews:myusercontrol>                      
    </StackPanel>
```

Inside myusercontrol I have the following implementation:

```
  public partial class MyUserControl
    {
        public delegate void SelectedTabItemHandler(string selectedTabItem);
        public event SelectedTabItemHandler TabItemSelected;

        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }     

        private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(TabItemSelected != null)
            {
                TabItemSelected("some selected Item");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I hook up the TabItemSelected event in my XAML like this:

```
<myviews:myusercontrol TabItemSelected="TabSelectionChanged"></myviews:myusercontrol>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For passing custom parameters I am doing something like this:

```
 public partial class PatientEditTabView : UserControl
    {       
        // Routed Event 
        public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectedTabItemEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TabItemSelected", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(PatientEditTabView));

        public PatientEditTabView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }     

        public event RoutedEventHandler TabItemSelected
        {
            add { AddHandler(SelectedTabItemEvent, value);  }
            remove { RemoveHandler(SelectedTabItemEvent, value); }
        }

        private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs eventArgs = new SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs(PatientEditTabView.SelectedTabItemEvent,tabControl.SelectedValue as String);
            RaiseEvent(eventArgs);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 3:**

```
 public class SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
    {
        private readonly String _selectedItem; 

        public SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent,string selectedItem)
            : base(routedEvent)
        {
            _selectedItem = selectedItem; 
        }

       public string SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create **`custom Routed event`** in case you want to hook handler from XAML.

Refer to the article here - [**How to create custom routed event.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

---

```
public partial class MyUserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent TabItemSelectedEvent = 
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TabItemSelected",
                     RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
                     typeof(MyUserControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler TabItemSelected
    {
        add { AddHandler(TabItemSelectedEvent, value); } 
        remove { RemoveHandler(TabItemSelectedEvent, value); }
    }

    void RaiseTabItemSelectedEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs =
                new RoutedEventArgs(MyUserControl.TabItemSelectedEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                             SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseTabItemSelectedEvent();
    }    
}
```

***Note***: You need to create class deriving from RoutedEventArgs in case you want to pass some custom data like string in your case and pass your custom event args while raising an event.

**UPDATE**:

Like I said you have to create derived class from RoutedEventArgs in case want to pass string value. This is how it will go:

```
public class SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    private readonly string selectedItem;

    public SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent,
                                      string selectedItem)
        :base(routedEvent)
    {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

and update other methods like this:

```
void RaiseTabItemSelectedEvent(string selectedItem)
{
    SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs newEventArgs =
          new SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs(SampleUserControl.TabItemSelectedEvent, 
                                         selectedItem);
    RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}

private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                            SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RaiseTabItemSelectedEvent(tabControl.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Also you target event handler in window will look like this:

```
private void TabSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs args = (SelectedTabRoutedEventArgs)e;
    string selectedItem = args.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on this, conceptually `UserControl` encapsulates and hides everything inside of it, so to expose underlying functionality you need to... wait for it... expose some sort of `RoutedEvent` or `DependencyProperty` on the `UserControl` itself!  It's a simple distinction but also something that is easily overlooked for some reason (at least it always confused me).

Comment: One question! How do I pass the selected value to the parent control?

Comment: Updated the original question with additional source about passing custom arguments.

Comment: I have update the answer with your follow up question. See if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason everytime I run I get the error mentioned in the updated post.

Comment: Post your `PatientEditTabView_TabItemSelected` event handler.

Comment: Just posted under UPDATE 2 heading in the original question. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: More likely the problem is in handler `TabSelectionChanged`. Use it like I provided in the answer above.

Comment: For some reason the tabControl.SelectedValue.ToString() is coming out to be System.Windows.Controls.TabItem Header:Visit Information Content:

Comment: That's because SelectedValue must be TabItem in your case. Fetch `Header` of SelectedValue and pass that instead like this - `(tabControl.SelectedValue as TabItem).Header`.

Comment: the "How to create custom routed event." link is ded :(
(I know this is kinda old, but I came here by searching, so guess others might as well.)

Comment: Thanks @OlleKelderman. Updated the link. Because of this issue only I added the code in answer itself.